# Using LeakCanary with HPROF File?

Tags: android, leakcanary

Short Question: Is it somehow possible to use the LeakCanary library with just the HPROF File and find leaks that way?

I already tried different stuff but failed as I dont have a KeyedWeakReference. I looked through all the classes and I am not 100% sure if I could create that by myself.

Has anyone every tried a scenario like this or is this library not suitable for this case?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have an HPROF file, use the HPROF analyzer in Android Studio. Or, use the standalone MAT tool from the Eclipse Foundation.

Comment: Okay. I am already working with that. I though I get more results using LeakCanary.

Comment: LeakCanary is more for automatically providing simpler-to-understand results.

Comment: That's also exactly what I though of and that's why I though It might be a good try as I get quick understandable results. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: have you solve this problem? I need tools to analyze hprof  automatically too.

Answer (score 0):

I found this , hope it can help you
Leak-canary provides a Heap file analysis engine named Shark
you can either call it by shark api or shark command line

you can download tools from this URL,
https://square.github.io/leakcanary/shark/

or just compile it by downloading source code and building  from leakcanary github website.

you can analyze heap file by the following commandline:

*shark-cli --hprof memory.dump  analyze*

or just by

*shark-cli -p   analyze*